# Integrate WinForms and Telegram using HTML5

Tags: c#, html, winforms, kendo-ui, telegram

As you probably know, Telegram has introduced its Gaming Platform recently which supports HTML5.
I developed a WinForms application. You know that Kendo UI supports HTML5, too. My question is that, is it possible to build an HTML5 page using Kendo UI and then render it into Telegram? If so, how?

Actually, since Telegram supports HTML5 from now on and since Kendo UI supports HTML5, so I want to make some HTML5 pages (Specially GridView) and load them into Telegram and users can interact with my WinForms application using their Telegram app.

If you have any idea about this, please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why no one helps me?